# Use Bindings with Core Data, SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

How can I use `@Binding`  with Core Data in SwiftUI?
If I use `$` in the `TextField`, I get the error `Cannot find '$row' in scope`, and if I don't use `$`, I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`.

CoreData Model:

```swift
extension User {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        return NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}

extension TimetableRowData : Identifiable {

}
```

SwiftUI View:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TimetableView: View {
      
    // Core Data
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
        
        SortDescriptor(\.name)
        
    ]) var users: FetchedResults<User>
    //
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
            
            ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    TextField("Username", text: $user.name) // <-- here I get an error 
            }
       }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Add User") {
                     let newUser = User(context: moc)
                     newUser.name = "Default Name"
                     try? moc.save()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution!

Comment: When you find a solution to a problem you've posted on StackOverflow, please post that solution as an official Answer to your question, so that other people can benefit from the solution as well.